# Why does the Kendo Grid show false in all records of my grid, even when some have true?

Tags: boolean, kendo-grid

I have put together a simple jsfiddle demonstrating the issue.  It has a grid with two records.  One has a true value in in the Boolean column and the other has a false.

I have logged the data to the console so you can see the values that the grid is getting.

Yet the grid shows false for both rows.

http://jsfiddle.net/codeowl/KhBMT/

Thanks for your time,

Scott

Code for StackOverflow:

```
var _Data = [
    { "SL_TestData_ID": "1", "SL_TestData_String": "Bool is 1", "SL_TestData_Boolean": "1" },
    { "SL_TestData_ID": "2", "SL_TestData_String": "Bool is 0", "SL_TestData_Boolean": "0" }
];

var _kendoDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: function (options) {
            console.log('Transport READ Event Raised - Data: ', JSON.stringify(_Data, null, 4));
            options.success(_Data);
        }
    },
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "SL_TestData_ID",
            fields: {
                SL_TestData_ID: { editable: false, nullable: false },
                SL_TestData_String: { type: "string" },
                SL_TestData_Boolean: { type: "boolean" }
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (a) {
        $('#TestGrid').data("kendoGrid").cancelChanges();
    }
});

// Initialize Grid
$("#TestGrid").kendoGrid({
    columns: [
        { field: "SL_TestData_ID", title: "ID" },
        { field: "SL_TestData_String", title: "String" },
        { field: "SL_TestData_Boolean", title: "Boolean" }
    ],
    dataSource: _kendoDataSource
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that if I altered my select statement to return "TRUE"/"FALSE" for my TINYINT column in the database it worked.  Eg;

```
SELECT 
    SL_TestData_ID,
    SL_TestData_Number, 
    SL_TestData_String, 
    SL_TestData_Date, 
    SL_TestData_DateTime,
    if (SL_TestData_Boolean = 1, "TRUE", "FALSE") as SL_TestData_Boolean
FROM
    SL_TestData;
```

Regards,

Scott